# Change html from place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change a row from a table to another but I want to replace the addBtn for a removeBtn.

`dataTableTeamMembers` is the other table

```js
$('.addBtn').click(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  console.log(row[1]);
  $('#dataTableTeamMembers tbody').append(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="text-center hover-table odd" role="row">
  <td class="sorting_1"><img class="avatarImage" src="data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw"></td>
  <td><a href="#">johns</a></td>
  <td>John Smith</td>
  <td>Member</td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addBtn"> Add</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: So, .find the button in your selected row, and change it’s class and text content accordingly …?

Answer (score 0):

update your js code with this.

```
 $('.addBtn').click(function () {
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            console.log(row[0]);
            $('#dataTableTeamMembers tbody').append(row[0].innerHTML);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.addBtn').click(function() {
  var row = $(".tbl .tbltr").html();
  console.log(row[1]);
  $('.tbl').append(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='tbl'>
<tr class="text-center hover-table odd tbltr" role="row">
  <td class="sorting_1"><img class="avatarImage" src="data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw"></td>
  <td><a href="#">johns</a></td>
  <td>John Smith</td>
  <td>Member</td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addBtn"> Add</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```